# Does Android provide any versioning mechanisms for AIDL interfaces?

Tags: android, aidl

We're planning to export an application layer AIDL interface. What are some best practices with regards for managing version compatibility? Does Android provide any version-related mechanisms for AIDL interfaces?

Answer (score 3):

Today - almost 6 years after you posted this question - I am asking myself the same question and there still seems to be no official solution.
The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) simply states:

> **Caution:** Any changes that you make to your AIDL interface after your first release must remain backward compatible in order to avoid breaking other applications that use your service. That is, because your .aidl file must be copied to other applications in order for them to access your service's interface, you must maintain support for the original interface.

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty trivial to put and verify either a string or integer version number in the parcel.